# Python custom list class initialization

Tags: python

Consider the class `AB` below that is to be used as a simple customized list of `A` objects for lookup operations.

Can this code be improved to avoid instantiating `AB` with an empty list `[]` (*i.e.*, perhaps modify `__add__` in some way)?

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

class AB():
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list = list

    def __add__(self, other):
        return AB(self.list + [other])

ab = AB([])
ab += A(1)
ab += A(2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can play with the default argument value:

```
class AB:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data if data is not None else []

    def __add__(self, other):
        return AB(self.data + [other.arg])
```

Other notes:

- `list` is a bad variable name as it is shadowing the built-in `list` keyword
- remove redundant parentheses after the class name

Demo:

```
In [1]: ab = AB()

In [2]: ab += A(1)

In [3]: ab += A(2)

In [4]: print(ab.data)
[<__main__.A instance at 0x10afb14d0>, <__main__.A instance at 0x10afa0998>]
```

Comment: I was looking for other ways to build `__add__`, but I guess that changing `__init__` works too. Thanks for the tips. Note that it is meant for `AB(self.data + [other])` (without `.arg`) in order to maintain a list of `A` objects.

Comment: @dfernan ah, gotcha, I'll remove the last suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: If you just use `data=[]` directly instead of be `None` indirection does that reuse a single list between `__init__` calls? Otherwise that seems cleaner.

Comment: Just got an opportunity to test. Yes, doing `data=[]` as a default argument leads to the same list being used for all invocations of `__init__`. However, this is only an issue if you implement `__iadd__`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that default arguments can (and should) be used for the backing list of your class.

In addition, consider inheriting from [`collections.abc.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) and delegating `__getitem__` and `__len__` to the backing list. (Add other list-like methods as necessary.) This will make sure your class acts as a well-behaved list-like.

In order to qualify as an [Iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), you must define [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) or [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). In order to qualify as a [Sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) you must be an Iterable that provides [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__). It's up to you how much functionality you want to provide, but the Sequence ABC exists for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

class AB():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        if not hasattr(self, '_list'):
            setattr(self, '_list', [other])
        else:
            self._list.append(other)

        return self

ab = AB()
ab += A(1)
ab += A(3)

print(ab._list[1].arg) # Prints 3
```

We completely avoid the creation of the `_list` parameter, unless we add an `A()` object.

Note that we are overriding the `+=` operator specifically.